# php + mysql число с плавающей точкой

Tags: php, mysql

как решить проблему:

в таблице есть вот такое число 0.00000042 и вот такое 2221853.0725

при выводе из базы первое число(0.00000042) выводит вот так 4.2e-7, а второе(2221853.0725) нормально

если я делаю `rtrim(number_format(0.00000042, 15, '.', '), '0')` то выводит правильно, но второе число `rtrim(number_format(2221853.0725, 15, '.', '), '0')` тогда выводит вот такое 2207198.951900000218302

Comment: Пока вы не определите какая вам нужна максимальная точность проблему вы не решите

Comment: поставил 8 знаков и все ок, спасибо, буду обдумывать

Comment: `(number_format(0.00000042, 15, '.', '),` тут ведь явно ошибка, как вообще что-то выводит непонятно

Comment: вместо числа с запятой там переменная стоит, это я для наглядности, с 15 тоже погорячился поставил 8

Comment: и то и другое не меняет сути - проблема после 3 параметра - в кач-ве четвёртого выступает просто одинарная кавычка